# Delete blocks in YAML file using Python

Tags: python, yaml

I have a YAML file that contains a Jenkins configuration as below:

```yaml
credentials:
  system:
    domainCredentials:
    - credentials:
      - usernamePassword:
          description: "github"
          id: "github"
          password: "{AQAAABAAAAAwHFhIFIYeda2gWu9qfLX8fRAOlQjdb+Eyo3K9EoYSCxT6nrTLt+QRKSBo4Sx4qOXH1Lfn2EjfAQfklR63XqWZAw==}"
          scope: GLOBAL
          username: "admin"
      - string:
          description: "test"
          id: "test"
          scope: GLOBAL
          secret: "{AQAAABAAAAAQyWoMCVDAldVDxS1J15gLzqTvo2Dr6j3ckrdX3C1/3sg=}"
jenkins:
  agentProtocols:
  - "JNLP4-connect"
  - "Ping"
  authorizationStrategy:
    loggedInUsersCanDoAnything:
      allowAnonymousRead: false
  crumbIssuer:
    standard:
      excludeClientIPFromCrumb: false
  disableRememberMe: false
  labelAtoms:
  - name: "master"
  markupFormatter: "plainText"
  mode: NORMAL
  myViewsTabBar: "standard"
  numExecutors: 2
  primaryView:
    all:
      name: "all"
  projectNamingStrategy: "standard"
  quietPeriod: 5
  remotingSecurity:
    enabled: true
  scmCheckoutRetryCount: 0
  securityRealm:
    local:
      allowsSignup: false
      enableCaptcha: false
      users:
      - id: "admin"
        name: "admin"
        properties:
        - "myView"
        - preferredProvider:
            providerId: "default"
        - "timezone"
        - mailer:
            emailAddress: "admin@test.net"
        - "apiToken"
  slaveAgentPort: 50000
  updateCenter:
    sites:
    - id: "default"
      url: "https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json"
  views:
  - all:
      name: "all"
  viewsTabBar: "standard"
security:
  apiToken:
    creationOfLegacyTokenEnabled: false
    tokenGenerationOnCreationEnabled: false
    usageStatisticsEnabled: true
  sSHD:
    port: -1
unclassified:
  artifactoryBuilder:
    jfrogPipelinesServer:
      bypassProxy: false
      connectionRetries: 3
      credentialsConfig:
        overridingCredentials: false
        username: "****"
      timeout: 300
    useCredentialsPlugin: false
  buildDiscarders:
    configuredBuildDiscarders:
    - "jobBuildDiscarder"
  buildStepOperation:
    enabled: false
  email-ext:
    adminRequiredForTemplateTesting: false
    allowUnregisteredEnabled: false
    charset: "UTF-8"
    debugMode: false
    defaultBody: |-
      $PROJECT_NAME - Build # $BUILD_NUMBER - $BUILD_STATUS:

      Check console output at $BUILD_URL to view the results.
    defaultSubject: "$PROJECT_NAME - Build # $BUILD_NUMBER - $BUILD_STATUS!"
    defaultTriggerIds:
    - "hudson.plugins.emailext.plugins.trigger.FailureTrigger"
    maxAttachmentSize: -1
    maxAttachmentSizeMb: -1
    precedenceBulk: false
    watchingEnabled: false
  fingerprints:
    fingerprintCleanupDisabled: false
    storage: "file"
  gitHubConfiguration:
    apiRateLimitChecker: ThrottleForNormalize
  gitHubPluginConfig:
    hookUrl: "http://localhost:8080/github-webhook/"
  gitSCM:
    addGitTagAction: false
    allowSecondFetch: false
    createAccountBasedOnEmail: false
    disableGitToolChooser: false
    hideCredentials: false
    showEntireCommitSummaryInChanges: false
    useExistingAccountWithSameEmail: false
  ivyBuildTrigger:
    extendedVersionMatching: false
  junitTestResultStorage:
    storage: "file"
  location:
    adminAddress: "address not configured yet <nobody@nowhere>"
    url: "http://localhost:8080/"
  mailer:
    charset: "UTF-8"
    useSsl: false
    useTls: false
  mavenModuleSet:
    localRepository: "default"
  pollSCM:
    pollingThreadCount: 10
  timestamper:
    allPipelines: false
    elapsedTimeFormat: "'<b>'HH:mm:ss.S'</b> '"
    systemTimeFormat: "'<b>'HH:mm:ss'</b> '"
tool:
  git:
    installations:
    - home: "git"
      name: "Default"
  mavenGlobalConfig:
    globalSettingsProvider: "standard"
    settingsProvider: "standard"
```

I need to delete two blocks "unclassified:" and "location:", how can I do that using Python?

Comment: Have you tried reading the YAML file, converting it to a Python data structure, removing the parts, converting it back to YAML and saving it to a file again?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pyyaml](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/) module to do this. Here's an example:

```py
import yaml

with open('file.yaml', 'r') as file:
    data = yaml.safe_load(file)
data.pop('unclassified')
with open('file.yaml', 'w') as file:
    yaml.safe_dump(data, file)
```

Comment: when run python3 script.py it didn't work >>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 5, in <module>
    del data['unclassifed']
KeyError: 'unclassifed'

Comment: I simply made a mistake in the 'unclassified' word, but now the code is correct.

Comment: Thanks it is working, but file format changed,

Comment: Well, it might have changed a bit, but I am sure it is still correct. There might be some keyword argument you can use with the safe_dump function to keep the previous format, but I am not sure about this.

Comment: i tried to delete "location" block it gives me, >> KeyError: 'location' >> what i noticed it can delete only main blocks but gives error with sub-blocks

Comment: You got nested data structures, and if you delete the 'unclassified' part, the 'location' is also deleted. If you only want to remove the 'location', you need to write something like this: "del data['unclassified']['location']". For such a task you just need learn how to perform basic operations on built-in data structures, like a dict or a list.

Comment: import yaml

with open('file.yaml') as f:    
    data = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

    del data['unclassified']['location']
    new = yaml.dump(data, sort_keys=True)
    print(new)